# REST API post request results in successful request but not creation

Tags: python, json, api, post, python-requests

I've been trying to make a Post Request to my CRM API. The CRM API is very vague:

"You can use POST request when you wish to create records. You POST a JSON encoded string to the servers and it will return a single instance of the record."

```
POST /{object_name}
```

Example:
Request URL (POST):

```
/accounts
```

Request Body (JSON):

```
{
    "name": "testing API"
}
```

I've had plenty of success making GET requests regularly, but POST is not working out so easily.

```
url = "https://apiv4.reallysimplesystems.com/accounts?<KEY>"

payload = {"name":"Ziggy","owner":"XYZ","addresscounty/state":"Awe","source":"Space"}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=<TOK>; really_simple_systems_session=<KEY>'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

I get a status code 200 when I run this, but I'm really looking for that 201. The only clue that I've got to follow at this point is that when I run:

```
response.json()
```

I get the error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I've tried switching the response parameters to json:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

I've tried ensuring that my payload is json by using json.dumps():

```
payload = {"name":"Ziggy","owner":"XYZ","addresscounty/state":"Awe","source":"Space"}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
```

And I've tried all sorts of other shenanigans that I can't even recall at this point. Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong here? The 200 status code makes me feel painfully close.

Comment: You can start by printing the response.content to see what the message is from the server. Most probably it has something to do with the syntax of your payload

Comment: The response essentially provides HTML Doc of the API page. In it here are fields for email and password, so I tried providing my email and password info as such  using auth = HTTPBasicAuth(<email>, <pw>) , but the response remained the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://apiv4.reallysimplesystems.com/accounts"

payload = {"name":"RSS Test Joe Bloggs","addresscounty/state":"Maryland","source":"Word of Mouth"}
payload = json.dumps(payload)
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <AUTH KEY>'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Rather than using Postman's code which included the  in the URL and used :

```
'Cookie': 'XSRF-TOKEN=<TOK>; really_simple_systems_session=<KEY>'
```

I replaced it with a standard Authorization header. Secondly, I found that using `json.dumps(payload)` and `json = payload` was resulting in a Bad Request.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<AUTH_TOKEN>` with your auth token

```py
url = "https://apiv4.reallysimplesystems.com/accounts/"

payload = {"name":"Ziggy"}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <AUTH_TOKEN>',
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My authorization token is properly entered. I'm using<AUTH TOKEN> to redact my security information.